# Example where std::array::max_size and std::array::size gives different result

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, stdarray

Whenever I try with `max_size()` and `size()` funtion of `std::array`, I get same results, I wanted to know if there could be a situation where two of them give different results.

Comment: From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/max_size: *"Because each std::array<T, N> is a fixed-size container, the value returned by max_size equals N (which is also the value returned by size)"*.

Answer (score 15):

That function exists for compatibility with other containers like `std::vector`. For `std::array` those two values will always be the same.

Answer (score 7):

Those two functions will always return the same value, namely `N` for an `std::array<T, N>`.

They are provided for consistency with other containers, for which the values will differ (e.g. `std::vector`).

Comment: I would say "consistency with other containers" is not proper description. Unfortunately all answers say that one way or another

Comment: @Slava How is it not a proper description? I don't see any value in dropping the phrase "container concept" here.

Comment: There are formal specifications (and I hope when they finally add concepts to the language they will be specified at that level) that certain containers must follow, yes I think describe that as "consistency with other" is not proper.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such example, because arrays are fixed-size containers. Their current size is the same as their maximum size because they cannot grow or shrink.

The reason `max_size()` is there at all is to let you use `std::array` in a way that is interchangeable with other containers from the C++ Standard Library.

There is no reason to use `max_size()` in contexts when your program knows the type of the container to be `std::array`.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::array::max_size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/max_size) returns the maximum number of elements that array can ever hope to contain. The size of an array is a compile-time constant and part of its type. It can only ever hold exactly that number of elements. The number of elements it contains and the number of elements it *could* contain are the same thing for `std::array`.

That particular function doesn't add much to `std::array`, but it exists for compatibility with other containers, which can store a variable number of elements. Consider the case where a function template expects some container type as argument. You may be interested in knowing that container's maximum storage capacity, rather it's `std::array` or another container.

Answer (score 2):

For `std::array` both functions are equal as stated in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/max_size). Despite duplication `std::array::max_size()` exists because `std::array` must satisfy concept [Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) which requires such method.